# "DNS not responding" error with D-Link router and PPTP internet connection

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dns

I have a D-Link DIR-615 router since around six months.

My internet connection is VPN (PPTP) based, i.e. I have been given a username and password from my ISP and my IP address is dynamic. Since a few days I am experiencing a serious problem. My router connects normally (I can see the yellow light), but my computer is giving me a "DNS not responding" error.

I have tried everything (reset, reboot etc.) but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Check the DNS server addresses your ISP would have given you and ensure they are set in your config. The most common problem I see with home routers is that the DHCP assignment can fail to provide a valid DNS server address.

If they are, try changing one to an alternative DNS server, for example, one of the OpenDNS one, in case the problem is with your ISP's DNS server.